# Is there a Windows system call I can make to view the number of OS threads a process is currently using?

Tags: windows

I've found the following question: [How can I view the active threads of a running program?](https://superuser.com/questions/462969/how-can-i-view-the-active-threads-of-a-running-program)

I can see the number of individual threads running for a process in task manager, which leads me to believe I should be able to obtain them through a system call.

Ex:
[image]

The answer suggests using the process explorer utility... but how is it obtaining the number of threads currently in use by a process?

If I knew the syscall, I could invoke it from another language such as Go lang. I need to access this information in my own software, not a GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Tool Help Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/toolhelp/tool-help-library) to retrieve information about threads in a process. In particular, you would use the [Thread32First](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tlhelp32/nf-tlhelp32-thread32first) and [Thread32Next](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tlhelp32/nf-tlhelp32-thread32next) functions to enumerate all the threads in the process.